# Remove name from name:value object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this array shown in console

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {num3: 1, num2: 1}
1: {num3: 2, num2: 4}
2: {num3: 3, num2: 1}
length: 3
pop: ƒ ()
push: ƒ ()
shift: ƒ ()
splice: ƒ ()
unshift: ƒ ()
_chartjs: {listeners: Array(1)}
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I just want to change the format to this

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {1, 1}
1: {2, 4}
2: {3, 1}
length: 3
pop: ƒ ()
push: ƒ ()
shift: ƒ ()
splice: ƒ ()
unshift: ƒ ()
_chartjs: {listeners: Array(1)}
__proto__: Array(0)
```

So then I can use it to draw a scatter chart using chart.js

Comment: I think there might be something a bit wrong. For the output, you can't have an object without keys. I think you mean to output a list of arrays.

Comment: impossible because `{1, 1}` is not a valid JS syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` function like so.

```
let newArr = oldArr.map(x => [x.num3, x.num2])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to output an array of arrays considering an object must have a key/value. To do so, this function should get the job done.

`const formatArr = (arr) => arr.map(({ num1, num2 }) => ([num1, num2]))`

You can then use this for multiple charts like so:

`const newChart = formatArr(oldChart)`

FYI: You should probably rename my function to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to remove the name, then you should turn to an object into an array of values.

you cant do this: `item = {1,2}` but you can do this `item = [1,2]`.

Considering you meant removing the properties which will lead to an array `[1,2]`, Try this:

```js
const arr = [
    {num3: 1, num2: 1},
    {num3: 2, num2: 4},
    {num3: 3, num2: 1}]

const arr2  = arr.map(k => Object.keys(k).map(ok => k[ok]))
console.log({arr2})
```

> Update: Looking at the scatter chart in `chart.js` you should have an `x` and a `y` as props instead, use this:

```js
const arr = [
    {num3: 1, num2: 1},
    {num3: 2, num2: 4},
    {num3: 3, num2: 1}]

// your object should be like this
const data  = arr.map(k => ({x: k.num3,y: k.num2}))

console.log(data)
```

*Reference: [Scatter Chart - Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/scatter.html)*